# Custom functions with TODAY() autorefresh when unrelated cells change

Tags: office-js, exceljs

I have a custom function which takes a date as an input. I can also use TODAY() as an input like this: `MY_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(TODAY())` and everything works fine.

Let say in my spreadsheet I have 2 cells which have values

A1: `=MY_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(TODAY())`

A2: `3`

Whenever I change the value of cell A2 (to 2, 4, or basically any value), cell A1 is refreshed. I am not sure why since cells A1 and A2 have nothing to do with each other. Is there any way to stop this autorefresh behavior? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Today is a volatile function. Hence by design it calculates similar to now function ie every time any cell changes in excel. You might want to create a non volatile today function to replace today.

Comment: Thanks. My custom function is used by other users so I can't really force them to use non-volatile today function while they are most likely only know the TODAY() function